# Why do I get an error in Scheme when I try to test for an empty list?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, scheme

I get this TypeError below that when I run the following code. I think it's because I'm trying to test for an empty list using "null?". Why is that causing an error?

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined [NumberLister, NumberLister, NumberLister, NumberLister, NumberLister, car]

```
(define NumberLister(lambda(numberList)

(if(null? numberList)
    (= (+ 1 1) 2)
)

(display (car numberList))
(display "\n")
(NumberLister (cdr numberList))
)
)

(NumberLister '(1 3 5 6))
```

Comment: Your recursion is unconditional - check your parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you can't put more than one expression in the consequent or alternative part of an `if` expression, if needed group the expressions in a `begin` form. Also, what's the use of `(= (+ 1 1) 2)`? just return `#t`, like this:

```
(define NumberLister
  (lambda (numberList)
    (if (null? numberList)
        #t
        (begin     
          (display (car numberList))
          (display "\n")
          (NumberLister (cdr numberList))))))
```